# Absolute positioning breaks in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, css-position

I am working on developing an asp.net control that I need to be able to drop into other applications.  The control is basically a custom dropdown in which a div gets displayed or hidden when another element is clicked.

The problem I am having is in trying to get the dynamic div to align below the element that gets clicked.  I wrote a javascript function which should, in theory, allow me to specify two elements and the desired alignment and then move the second element to the correct position in relation to the first element.

I have three test cases which relate to places where I currently expect this control will be used, my current markup and javascript work in all three cases for IE7 but fails for one of the cases in FF3.5 and IE8-standards mode.  I have been playing with this for a while and have yet to come up with an answer that fixes the problem case without breaking one of the others.  (Note that 90+% of my users are on IE7 with a slow migration towards IE8)

I am looking for any suggestions other than adding a compatibility mode directive to the page, that does fix things in IE8 but I would prefer an alternative if one is possible since I may not always have control over where this is used.  Here is an HTML doc which illustrates the relevant markup and javascript along with the test cases. Case three is the one which has problems, instead of aligning neatly under the input element the div is overlapping vertically and offset to the right by a distance equivalent to the width of the select element.

(Note that the real pages utilize a reset style sheet adapted from the one published by Eric Meyer, including/omitting this style sheet has no relevant effect on these test cases.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var VAlign = { "top": -1, "center": 0, "bottom": 1 };
    var HAlign = { "left": -1, "center": 0, "right": 1 };
    function AlignElements(element1, vAlign1, hAlign1, element2, vAlign2, hAlign2) {
        var List1 = BuildOffsetList(element1);
        var List2 = BuildOffsetList(element2);
        var Index1 = List1.length - 1;
        var Index2 = List2.length - 1;

        while (Index1 >= 0 && Index2 >= 0 && List1[Index1] == List2[Index2]) {
            Index1--;
            Index2--;
        }

        element2.style.top = "";
        element2.style.left = "";

        var OT1 = 0;
        var OL1 = 0;
        var OT2 = 0;
        var OL2 = 0;

        while (Index1 >= 0) {
            OT1 += List1[Index1].offsetTop;
            OL1 += List1[Index1].offsetLeft;
            Index1--;
        }

        while (Index2 >= 0) {
            OT2 += List2[Index2].offsetTop;
            OL2 += List2[Index2].offsetLeft;
            Index2--;
        }

        var top = (OT1 - OT2);
        if (vAlign1 == VAlign.bottom) {
            top += element1.offsetHeight;
        } else if (vAlign1 == VAlign.center) {
            top += (element1.offsetHeight / 2);
        }
        if (vAlign2 == VAlign.bottom) {
            top -= element2.offsetHeight;
        } else if (vAlign2 == VAlign.center) {
            top -= (element2.offsetHeight / 2);
        }

        var left = (OL1 - OL2);
        if (hAlign1 == HAlign.right) {
            left += element1.offsetWidth;
        } else if (hAlign1 == HAlign.center) {
            left += (element1.offsetWidth / 2);
        }
        if (hAlign2 == HAlign.right) {
            left -= element2.offsetWidth;
        } else if (hAlign2 == HAlign.center) {
            left -= (element2.offsetWidth / 2);
        }

        element2.style.top = top + "px";
        element2.style.left = left + "px";
    }

    function BuildOffsetList(elelment) {
        var I = 0;
        var List = new Array();
        var Element = elelment;
        while (Element) {
            List[I] = Element;
            Element = Element.offsetParent;
            I++;
        }
        return List;
    }
</script>
Case 1
<div>
    <div id="control1" style=" display:inline; position:relative;">
        <div id="control1_div1" style="background-color:Blue; height:75px; width:150px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <input id="control1_txt1" type="text" style="width:150px;" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AlignElements(document.getElementById("control1_txt1"), VAlign.bottom, HAlign.left, document.getElementById("control1_div1"), VAlign.top, HAlign.left);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
Case 2
<div>
    <div id="Nav" style="float:left; width:200px; height:150px; background-color:Aqua;"></div>
    <div id="Content" style="margin-left:200px; height:150px; background-color:#ddd;">
        <div style="margin-left:100px;">
            <h5 style="float:left; margin-left:-100px; width:90px; margin-right:10px; text-align:right; font-weight:.9em;">Label</h5>
            <div id="control2" style=" display:inline; position:relative;">
                <div id="control2_div1" style="background-color:Blue; height:75px; width:150px; position:absolute;"></div>
                <input id="control2_txt1" type="text" style="width:150px;" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    AlignElements(document.getElementById("control2_txt1"), VAlign.bottom, HAlign.left, document.getElementById("control2_div1"), VAlign.top, HAlign.left);
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
Case 3
<div>
    <select><option>something</option></select>
    <br />
    <select><option>something else</option></select>
    <div id="control3" style=" display:inline; position:relative;">
        <div id="control3_div1" style="background-color:Blue; height:75px; width:150px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <input id="control3_txt1" type="text" style="width:150px;" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AlignElements(document.getElementById("control3_txt1"), VAlign.bottom, HAlign.left, document.getElementById("control3_div1"), VAlign.top, HAlign.left);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using jQuery it should be much easier to place element besides/below other element.. is this a valid option for you?

Comment: I don't have control over everywhere this will be used so I am trying hard to stay in the realm of standard javascript. If all else fails I might get away with importing another library to build off of, but I would prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shadow Wizard for getting me thinking in the right direction.  Turns out that the issue is that my absolutely positioned elements do not move to their 0,0 point when I clear the top and left properties.  If I change the code to explicitly put them at 0,0 before calculating the offset difference then everything works beautifully.

```
    element2.style.top = "";
    element2.style.left = "";
```

becomes

```
    element2.style.top = "0px";
    element2.style.left = "0px";
```

Answer (score 1):

The third case is breaking apart because of the `inline` display of the parent `div` - it cause the relative position to have no effect as far as I know.

To test such case use float instead, here is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/estYF/1/

Comment: Floats would cause problems on the pages where this needs to be used but points for getting my brain onto the right track.